Cannot find dependencies when building project on Android Studio Ladybug
I just switched my dev machine to a newer one. So I unzip a project (which is created on older AS about 2 years ago) to ~/AndroidStudioProjects
When building on AS Ladybug, suddenly I found these errors:
14: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAndroidTestDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.an.deviceinfo:deviceinfo:0.1.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/an/deviceinfo/deviceinfo/0.1.5/deviceinfo-0.1.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/an/deviceinfo/deviceinfo/0.1.5/deviceinfo-0.1.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/an/deviceinfo/deviceinfo/0.1.5/deviceinfo-0.1.5.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/an/deviceinfo/deviceinfo/0.1.5/deviceinfo-0.1.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:8.6.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/8.6.7/mapbox-android-sdk-8.6.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/8.6.7/mapbox-android-sdk-8.6.7.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/8.6.7/mapbox-android-sdk-8.6.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/8.6.7/mapbox-android-sdk-8.6.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not resolve cz.kinst.jakub:android-stateful-layout-simple:2.0.7.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve cz.kinst.jakub:android-stateful-layout-simple:2.0.7.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/cz/kinst/jakub/android-stateful-layout-simple/2.0.7/android-stateful-layout-simple-2.0.7.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/cz/kinst/jakub/android-stateful-layout-simple/2.0.7/android-stateful-layout-simple-2.0.7.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

This is the build.gradle of my project:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

And settings.gradle:
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "XXXXXXXXXX"
include ':app'

Invalidating the cache, resync from Gradle etc doesn't solve the issue.
Any hints?
